# Detecting duplicate keys with Play Json

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a Scala application using the Play Framework's json library. I know that json generally allows duplicate keys in an object. However, I would like to disallow duplicate keys in json given as an input to my application.

How can I tell whether a json document has duplicate keys? If I have the source of the document as a string and I parse it with Json.parse, this ignores the duplicate keys (takes the last value for the key only), which means that I cannot tell that there was a duplicate key by examining the JsValue it returns to me.

I was hoping that play.api.libs.json.JsonConfiguration would provide a way to change this behavior, but it is does not.

Is there a way to programmatically tell whether a string of Json source has duplicate keys using Play?

Comment: No you cannot, `JsObject` is a `Map` of field, no duplicate

Comment: Thanks. I understand that by the time I have a JsObject it is too late, but I still thought there might be some way to tell programmatically before that point, when I have the json source

Comment: There is no such intermediate representation